# Is there a way to make an HTTP request reach a server at an exact time?

Tags: httprequest, timing

I am creating a nodejs program that sends HTTP requests. I want the HTTP requests to reach the server at an exact time. For example, I might want to send an HTTP requeset and have it reach the server at exactly Tuesday, August 6, 2019 1:00:00 PM, or 1565096400000 (epoch timestamp in milliseconds).
How would I do this?

One thing I've considered is using setTimeout() to time my requests at a certain time, but the time at which they reach the server is inconsistent.

Here is an example of a using setTimeout to time my requests.
In this example, I would want the request to reach the server at exactly 1565096400000 (epoch timestamp).

```
var options = {
    url = 'someurl.com';
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log('Error.');
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

var time_until_request = 1565096400000 - Date.now(); 
//We want the request to reach the server at exactly 1565096400000 (epoch //timestamp).

var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    request(options, callback);
},time_until_request);
```

Of course, with what I am doing, the request won't reach the server at the time I want it to. It will reach the server some time before or after - I believe due to inconsistencies with latency.

Comment: How do you propose to do this when network latency and routing aren't consistent? Are you connecting directly to a specific IP address over a restricted route that you can control? If not, you're out of luck. You can control when you send the request, but you can't control precisely when it's received.

Comment: Yeah the question was if there was any way to do this. But I don't have much control over the route.

Comment: Then I think I've given you then information you need, which is that you're out of luck. If you can't control the exact route through every single step, you can't do what you ask.